# Need help figuring out why my csv output is blank?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I wrote this code to create a .csv report from an .xml file, but when I open the .csv that's generated it's blank. Feel free to rip my code apart, by the way, I'm super new to this and want to learn!

There are multiple "Subjectkeys" in the xml, but only some have an "AuditRecord". I only want to pull ones with an audit record, and then for those, I want to pull their info from "SubjectData", "FormData" and "AuditRecord"

```
import csv
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("response.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

xml_data_to_csv =open("query.csv", 'w')



AuditRecord_head = []
SubjectData_head = []
FormData_head = []

csvwriter=csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)
count=0
for member in root.findall("AuditRecord"):
    AuditRecord = []
    Subjectdata = []
    FormData = []
    if count == 0:
        Subject = member.find("SubjectKey").tag
        Subjectdata_head.append(Subject)
        Form = member.find("p1Name").tag
        FormData_head.append(Form)
        Action = member.find("Action").tag
        AuditRecord_head.append(Action)
        csvwriter.writerow(Auditrecord_head)
        count = count + 1
    Subject = member.find('SubjectKey').text
    Subjectdata.append(Subject)
    Form = member.find('p1Name').text
    FormData.append(Form)
    Action = member.find("Action").text
    AuditRecord.append(Action)

    csvwriter.writerow(Subjectdata)
xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

I expect the output to be a table with column headings: Subject, Form, Action.

Here is sample .xml:

```
 </ClinicalData>
    <ClinicalData StudyOID="SMK-869-002" MetaDataVersionOID="2.0">
    <SubjectData SubjectKey="865-015">
</AuditRecord>
</FormData>
<FormData p1:Name="Medical History" p1:Started="Y" FormOID="mh" FormRepeatKey="0"/>
<FormData p1:Name="Medical History" p1:Started="Y" FormOID="mh" FormRepeatKey="1">
<p1:QueryAction InitialComment="Please enter start date for condition" UserType="User" UserOID="bailey@protocolfirst.com" Action="query" DateTimeStamp="2019-07-12T14:08:43.893Z"/>
</AuditRecord>
```

Comment: Is `xml_data_to_csv.close()` really indented inside the `for` loop?

Comment: The only reason I can think of for the file being empty is that `root.findall("AuditRecord")` is not finding anything.

Comment: The variable "csv_writer" is declared, but then never used. "csvwriter" is used instead. Does this code run without error? If you provide a sample response.xml, others can run it.

Comment: I made a couple edits - xml_data_to_csv.close is not indented in my actual code. I also updated my code to change csv_writer to csvwriter, but still same result.

Comment: Just added some sample lines from the xml file

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: The XML you've shown us is a complete mess, with unmatched end tags.

Comment: The actual document is not like that, I was trying to shorten it down for posting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your xml file has a lot of errors, to me it has to look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:p1="http://some-url.com">
    <ClinicalData StudyOID="SMK-869-002" MetaDataVersionOID="2.0"></ClinicalData>
    <SubjectData SubjectKey="865-015"></SubjectData>
    <AuditRecord>
        <FormData p1:Name="Medical History" p1:Started="Y" FormOID="mh" FormRepeatKey="0"/>
        <FormData p1:Name="Medical History" p1:Started="Y" FormOID="mh" FormRepeatKey="1"/>
        <p1:QueryAction InitialComment="Please enter start date for condition" UserType="User" UserOID="bailey@protocolfirst.com" Action="query" DateTimeStamp="2019-07-12T14:08:43.893Z"/>
    </AuditRecord>
</root>
```

ElementTree always expects only a single root node, and a well-formed document.

I do not understand very well what your trying to do, but I hope this could help you:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("response.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

xml_data_to_csv = open("query.csv", 'w')

list_head=[]

count=0
for member in root.findall("AuditRecord"):
    AuditRecord = []
    Subjectdata = []
    FormData = []
    if count == 0:
        Subjectdata.append(root.find('./SubjectData').attrib['SubjectKey'])

        for formData in root.findall('./AuditRecord/FormData'):
            #print(formData.attrib['{http://some-url.com}Name'])
            FormData.append(formData.attrib['{http://some-url.com}Name'])

        AuditRecord.append(root.find('./AuditRecord/{http://some-url.com}QueryAction').attrib['Action'])

        xml_data_to_csv.write(Subjectdata[0] + "," + FormData[0] + "," + FormData[1] + "," + AuditRecord[0])
        count = count + 1

xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

This will produce a csv file with the following content:

```
865-015,Medical History,Medical History,query
```

Comment: Thanks - I realize I was not clear. There are multiple subjectkeys in the xml, but only some have an "AuditRecord". I only want to pull ones with an audit record, and then for those, I want to pull their info from "SubjectData", "FormData" and "AuditRecord".